# How to filter the data in a grid, by the parameter from another grid in extjs4?

Tags: filter, grid, extjs4

I have 2 grids that receive data from two stores. The first grid contains information about the commodity transaction, and the second contains the list of goods for each operation. They are related to each other by the meaning of the operation code. It is required to implement an operation table filter based on the product code from the second table. Is it possible to do it somehow on the client, using the framework tools or only through server processing?

Comment: It is now right way of asking question. You firstly need to show the work you did. The structure must be like  this , I did X expecting Y but i got Z

Comment: Plese edit your question so it's clear what is your desired behaviour. You can also look into `Ext.data.Store` methods [`filter`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filter) and [`filterBy`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filterBy).